# Slow NFS, nfsstat -c: what is authrefrsh (aka newcreds?) field about in detail?

Tags: gentoo, nfs, openvpn

(net-fs/nfs-utils-1.2.3-r1, 2.6.38.5-zen+ Gentoo)

Googling this seems to be a complete dead end. [man nfsstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nfsstat) says a whole lot of nothing about the subject. The closest I could get was finding out about what was probably previously "[newcreds](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftungd/doc/prftungd/nfsstat_c_command.htm)".

> newcreds
>       Number of times authentication information had to be refreshed.

My problem is that I *think* I'm seeing subpar NFS performance over OpenVPN and the only thing I can immediately see that is significantly different than all nfsstat Google results, is that my "calls" field equals exactly "authrefrsh" and is therefore very high. All the search result outputs always had authrefrsh as 0 or a very low number. Before I can move on to debugging some other aspects, I could use finding out what this means.

Watched operation is emerging a package over NFS-shared portage. emerge does traverse a big tree during it's operation but previous experience says the performance I'm seeing is abnormal.

```
$ watch -n 1 nfsstat -c

Every 1,0s: nfsstat -c                                Sat May 21 23:04:55 2011

Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
308565     2211       308565

Client nfs v3:
null         getattr      setattr      lookup       access       readlink
0         0% 172372   55% 17        0% 30485     9% 36057    11% 26831     8%
read         write        create       mkdir        symlink      mknod
25879     8% 107       0% 21        0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%
remove       rmdir        rename       link         readdir      readdirplus
16        0% 0         0% 11        0% 0         0% 0         0% 16668     5%
fsstat       fsinfo       pathconf     commit
3         0% 50        0% 25        0% 2         0%
```

I can't figure out exactly what authrefrsh is (and this spelling, is that intentional btw?) and why is it increasing like this in my case?

Comment: When you say slow NFS, what leads you to believe that the NFS performance should be faster?  Can you quantify slow?  Does time of day matter WRT performance?

Comment: "Slow NFS" means that NFS traffic should have no trouble taking up whole bandwidth available, which over VPN wasn't that much (100 kB/sec). Instead iftop was showing me traffic of only single digit kB/sec over tun0. I believe I have narrowed the problem down to Portage stat'ing a couple of thousand packages in my PKGDIR during binpkg related emerge runs, which seems to be excruciatingly slow operation. From what I can tell so far, the best solution might be having regularly updated squashfs portage on the remote workstations and getting binpkgs over HTTP binhost, instead of NFS-mounted PKGDIR.

Comment: Any updates on this?  I've noticed poorer NFS client performance with newer SLES 11 and CentOS 6 servers when compared to our older SLES 9 servers.  SLES 9 clients are speedier, and also show `authrefrsh=0`, while the newer OS' show a ton of `authrefrsh`.  I think there is a correlation here, but not quite sure what this all means.

Comment: What type of NFS authentication are you doing? `AUTH_SYS`?

Comment: To answer part of your question though, authrefrsh is the number of times the NFS client has called `call_refresh()` which is basically  going out to the RPC server (portmap, rpcbind, etc) and validating its credentials with the server. We need to figure out if it's actually what's causing the latency. If you're doing `AUTH_SYS` then the overhead is low and wouldn't be the cause.

Comment: Theres a Red Hat knowledgebase article [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/61980), but I don't have access to it.  If someone does, they could paste it as an answer here and collect a handsome bounty.

Comment: @JoelDavis I'm not sure what type of authentication I'm doing.  I'm using NFSv3, and I don't believe I have many choices in that department.  I can do an `strace` and find out whats going on behind the scenes, if thats more of what you're asking.

Comment: @Benjer yeah I read that article just says basically what I said earlier about call_refresh. Here is a copy/paste of the article: http://dpaste.org/IMp5V/

Comment: If you're not using NIS and you're unsure, you're using AUTH_SYS. Alternatives are kerberos and NIS. Hard to imagine being unaware of kerberized NFS. That said, it's probably not related to your issue. Have you done throughput tests to see if it's a VPN issue?

Comment: BTW, AUTH_SYS means it trusts the other system to authenticate users to a UID (even if it does a root squash, it'll still do AUTH_SYS and the server will map to the nobody user on its side).

Comment: @JoelDavis sounds like I'm using `AUTH_SYS` then.  On the server end, we have to allow the client's IP when setting up a new client to be able to mount a share, but thats it.  As far as I've read, thats the only authentication thats done with NFS version 3.

Comment: @JoelDavis, can you summarize that article plus your earlier comments in an answer here?  I'll accept it then.  I think its suffice to say that it is not causing additional overhead, at least in my case.  i.e. these calls have always been there, but now its just that the counter as shown in `nfsstat` is being incremented.

Comment: yeah, even if you were the OP, I'd feel weird about accepting bounty without fixing the underlying problem.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Red Hat article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61980) in the comments the solution says

> This is expected behaviour.

Not very helpful but it also points out the reason it happens.

It references commit a17c2153d2e271b0cbacae9bed83b0eaa41db7e1 in the sunrpc package that moves where nfs authentication takes place. I won't copy/paste the entire commit but it mostly changes these lines.

```
-struct rpc_cred *cred = task->tk_msg.rpc_cred;
+struct rpc_cred *cred = task->tk_rqstp->rq_cred;
```

My limited understanding is that this line moves where the call_refresh() happens (sooner rather than later). This in turn means most all nfs requests will cause authrefrsh to increment as authentication is always used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same thing (not using vpn) - authrefrsh == calls on the client side. It seems to me like the number of calls increases, then slows down, and the number of authrefrsh then catches up.

Client rpc stats:

```
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
261697     0          261697
```

I see very high iowait too:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/omoikane/testfile bs=16k count=2048
```

(from iostat:)

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          4.04    0.00    4.04   91.92    0.00    0.00
```

I
can't see anything unusual in wireshark - I'm using nfs3 and tcp.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from this link, authrefresh = calls isn't indicating a problem.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=785931

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: what they mean is they're not sure it's the cause of the problem or just going up due to it. "skyrocketing" is definitely indicating things aren't fine. similarly this is mostly seen in parallel with ugly perf issues.